# Creating Hashtable as final in java

Tags: java, hashtable

As we know the purpose of "final" keyword in java. While declaring a variable as final, we have to initialize the variable. like "**final int a=10;"**
   We can not change the value of "a". But if we go for HashTable its possible to add some value even declaring the HashTable as final.

Example::

```
 private static final Hashtable<String,Integer> MYHASH = new Hashtable<String,Integer>() 
{{     put("foo",      1);     
       put("bar",      256);     
       put("data",     3);     
       put("moredata", 27);     
       put("hello",    32);     
       put("world",    65536);  }};
```

Now I am declaring the MYHASH HashTable as final. If I try to add some more elements to this, its accepting.

```
MYHASH.put("NEW DATA",      256);
```

Now the "NEW DATA" is added to the HashTable.
My questions is Why its allowing to add even its declaring as final????

Comment: Note if contents of the map were mutable (`java.util.Date` or `java.awt.Point`, say) then it's still mutable.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Because final marks the reference, not the object. You can't make that reference point to a different hash table. But you can do anything to that object, including adding and removing things.

Your example of an `int` is a primitive type, not a reference. Final means you cannot change the value of the variable. So, with an `int` you cannot change the value of the variable, e.g. make the value of the `int` different. With an object reference, you cannot change the value of the reference, i.e. which object it points to.

Answer (score 24):

You can use [`Collections.unmodifiableMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) to get an unmodifiable wrapper over your hash table.

Example:

```
import java.util.*;
class Test{

    public static final Map<String,Integer> MYHASH;
    static{
        Hashtable<String,Integer> tmp = 
            new Hashtable<String,Integer>();
        tmp.put("A",65);
        tmp.put("C",67);
        MYHASH = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmp);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(MYHASH.get("A"));

        //this will throw
        //java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        MYHASH.put("B",66);    

    }

}
```

Comment: You get my +1 because you clearly aren't keeping the mutable version of the map about to get inadvertently mutated. Would have preferred to keep the immutable static `private`. Also no point in using `Hashtable`.

Comment: Thank you! I went with `Hashtable` for consistency with the question, but I hadn't noticed the `private`.

Answer (score 16):

Only the reference is final, its methods can of course be called just as for a non-final reference.

Use `Collections.unmodifiableMap(map)` to make a map unmodifiable.

Answer (score 8):

Try and wrap your `Hashtable` with an unmodifiable map using `Collections.unmodifiableMap( MYHASH  )`. This should throw exceptions when you try to change something in the map, i.e. add or remove entries. (Note that `MYHASH` should then be of type `Map<String, String>` and not  `Hashtable<String, String>`.)

Regarding the `final` keyword: as the others already said, it means that you can't assign another `Hashtable` to `MYHASH` but the map itself is still mutable. To change this you have to wrap it with some immutable wrapper, like the `UnmodifiableMap` mentioned above.

Answer (score 6):

As Joe said, this is because `final` marks the reference not the object.

However, you can do what you want with `Collections.unmodifiableMap` (see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap%28java.util.Map%29))

Answer (score 3):

For fields and variables, using `final` means they can be assigned only once. Either immediately, or at some later time (e.g. in a constructor for fields). This doesn't mean the actual instance becomes immutable. A Hashtable is a data structure that you can add entries to, regardless of how it was assigned to some variable. Only the **reference** is final.