# Is there a Java HashMap implementation where key-values can't be changed after initial insertion?

Tags: java, hashmap

I was going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7996499/10153731) question on creating a `HashTable<K,V>` as `final`. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7996585/10153731) answer where we use `Collections.unmodifiableMap` to put an un-modifiable wrapper over the hash table. This got me wondering if there is a `HashMap` implementation or any other similar structure, where I can insert whenever I want but once I've inserted a key and value, another insertion on the same key is not allowed.

For eg:

```
private final HashMap<Integer, Integer> test = new HashMap<>();
test.put(1, 100);
test.put(2, 200);
/*
* Other insertions
*/
test.put(1, 50); //This should not be allowed
```

One solution which I can think of is to do:

```
if(test.get(1) == null) {
    test.put(1, 50); //Similarly for all insertions
}
```

or to create a method which will do this check, like:

```
private void putIfNotPresent(int key, int value) {
    if(test.get(key) == null) { //Considering that null will be returned if there is no mapping available for the key
        test.put(key, value);
    } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException;
    }
}
```

I'm also aware of the [`putIfAbsent(K, V)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) method, but this also will not disallow if someone tries to `put()` some value for an already existing key.

All the solutions which I've come up with won't stop someone from inserting into the HashMap if the key is already present, unless they use the `putIfNotPresent()` custom method or the `putIfAbsent` method for every insertion. Is there such a `HashMap` implementation available where once a key and value is inserted, insertion on the same key is disallowed i.e. once a key is inserted with a value, it should act as if the key's value is `final`?

Comment: (AFAIK) No, there isn't.  But you could write a custom `Map` class with those properties.

Comment: Just a question: why throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` instead of an `IllegalStateException`? It's logical to throw the `IllegalStateException` because when the map tries to introduce a duplicate, it's in an illegal state for that operation with those parameters.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire I just added that exception as kind of a placeholder to indicate that it shouldn't happen. It is more logical to throw an `IllegalStateException`. Thanks for the input!

Comment: well, `ConcurrentHashMap` has a method [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)) that does that, but it does not prevent modification through other methods. More generally, [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) may also be useful in this context.

Comment: @Hulk is it not similar to the [`putIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) method of the default `HashMap` except that the action is performed atomically?

Comment: @MathewThomas ah yes,you are right, it is also on the [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#putIfAbsent(K,V)) interface. I somehow misremembered it being specific to CHM. I guess I missed that this has been added to Map with java 8 (this was made possible by default-methods). CHM had it since 1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such implementation by default. However, you can easily make one using Guava's [`ForwardingMap`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ForwardingMap.html):

```
class FailOnDupeMap<K,V> extends ForwardingMap<K,V> {
  private final Map<K,V> delegate = new HashMap<>();
  protected Map<K, V> delegate() { return delegate; } 
  @Override public V put(K key, V value) {
    var result = delegate().putIfAbsent(key, value);
    checkState(result == null, "a value already exist for key %s", key);
    return null;
  }
  @Override public void putAll(Map<? extends K,​ ? extends V> map) {
    standardPutAll(map);
  }
}
```

I wrote a default implementation of `putAll`, but throwing exception based on state depends so much on you that you probably want to change it to suit your needs: either no insertion at all or insert until a dupe is found.

Also, please note that I chose to throw an `IllegalStateException` when a dupe is found, but that exception is *not* declared in the `Map` interface. No exception declared in the `Map` interface should be thrown based on state. So you'd better well document it and say that this implementation breaks the Map interface in that regards.

Comment: Is there any additional benefit in implementing this using Guava's `ForwardingMap`? If you see, Harshal's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68620269/10153731) below, it doesn't use an external library.

Comment: @MathewThomas This solution is, in my views, way cleaner than Harshal Parekh's answer, for multiple reasons. First, `ForwardingMap` is *meant to be extended*, while `HashMap` isn't (it can be extended, but it isn't *meant* to be extended). Second, it uses encapsulation rather than extension. If you want to use a `TreeMap` tomorrow or pass a specific instance tomorrow, it's easy as pie to adapt. With Harshal's solution, it's hard and complex. Third, the class is named, and therefore reusable. With Harshal's solution, you have to rewrite it everytime you want to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `.put()` something like this:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> test =
    new HashMap<Integer, Integer>() {
      @Override
      public Integer put(Integer key, Integer value) {
        // handle do not insert logic here
        if (this.containsKey(key)) {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
        
        // key not in map, insert
        return super.put(key, value);
      }
    };
```